# geoplugin php giving country and ip of hosting server

Tags: php, hosting

I'm using geoplugin php to get the country and ip of visitors on my site, but its returning the ip and country of hosting server instead of user who visit the site, I'm using Hostinger as my hosting.

```
$ipdat = @json_decode(file_get_contents("http://www.geoplugin.net/json.gp")); 
$country = $ipdat->geoplugin_countryName; 
$ip = $ipdat->geoplugin_request;
```

its working fine on xampp localhost.

Comment: It does make sense if it returns IP of the server where this script is running.

Comment: Check the documentation at https://www.geoplugin.com/webservices/php to see how you are supposed to use it.

Comment: With $_SERVER, you receive data of the user/visitor

Comment: Where I can use $_server @vivek_23

Comment: You aren't passing the IP address anywhere in your code, that should give you a clue ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code behavior is an expected behavior since the GEO plugin site gets the IP address from where the script request came and gives details accordingly. If you want user/visitor's data, then you will need to make use of user's remote IP stored in `$_SERVER` global variable and pass this IP to GEO plugin to get the details as mentioned in their [`docs`](https://www.geoplugin.com/webservices/php).

**Snippet:**

```
<?php

$data = unserialize(file_get_contents('http://www.geoplugin.net/php.gp?ip='.$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']));

$country = $data['geoplugin_countryName'];
$ip = $data['geoplugin_request'];

echo $country," ",$ip,"<br/>";

print_r($data);
```